# Chrome flag on Android: --use-file-for-fake-video-capture not working

Tags: android, google-chrome, webrtc, adb, getusermedia

I wanted to inject a video into the WebRTC `getUserMedia()` in an **Android device running Chrome**. But the flag `--use-file-for-fake-video-capture` is not working (WebRTC is giving a NotFoundError) even though the path seems to be valid.

What I did:

1. Enabled the flag "Enable command line on non-rooted devices" in
   `chrome://flags`
2. Added the below flags to `/data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line`

```
_
--use-fake-device-for-media-stream
--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=/sdcard/example.y4m
```

```
('_' is required for the flags to work)
```

3. I also tried omitting permutations of the above flags. Didn't work. `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream` and `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream` alone work perfectly.
4. I tried changing path from `/sdcard/example.y4m` to `/storage/emulated/0/example.y4m`. Didn't work
5. The file `example.y4m` is working fine since I tested the same flags on Chrome running on my Mac.
6. I verified that the flags are being enabled in `chrome://version`

Device Info: Pixel 5, Rooted & bootloader unlocked